# C++ SFML Button not working :/

Tags: c++, button, sfml, 2d-games

I am trying to make a c++ sfml game but the button I have created doesn't seem to be working and I have it on good authority that it should. Please help me, the button by the way is, "if (mouseposx > 1366 / 2.0 && mouseposx < 1083)...".

Main Menu.h

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace sf;
using namespace std;
#pragma once

class main_menu
{
public:
void startmenu(RenderWindow &gameDisplay, Font &font1, bool &MainMenu, int &mouseposx, int &mouseposy)
{
    gameDisplay.setMouseCursorVisible(true);
    RectangleShape start(Vector2f(400, 100));
    start.setFillColor(Color(0, 0, 0));
    start.setOutlineThickness(20);
    start.setOutlineColor(Color(255, 255, 255));

    FloatRect startRect = start.getLocalBounds();
    start.setOrigin(startRect.width / 2, startRect.height / 2);
    start.setPosition(Vector2f(1366 / 2.0f, 768 - 450.0f));



    Text starttext;
    starttext.setCharacterSize(100);
    starttext.setFont(font1);
    starttext.setString("DODGE");
    starttext.setFillColor(Color(255, 255, 255));
    starttext.setStyle(Text::Bold);

    FloatRect starttextRect = starttext.getLocalBounds();
    starttext.setOrigin(starttextRect.width / 2, starttextRect.height / 2);
    starttext.setPosition(Vector2f(1366 / 2.0f - 30, 768 - 700.0f));



    while (MainMenu == true)
    {
        /*
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::P))
        {
            MainMenu = false;

        }
        */

        mouseposx = (Mouse::getPosition(gameDisplay).x);
        mouseposy = (Mouse::getPosition(gameDisplay).y);
        cout << "Position of mouse y is" << mouseposy << endl;
        cout << "Position of mouse x is" << mouseposx << endl;


            if (mouseposx > 1366 / 2.0 && mouseposx < 1083)
                if (mouseposy > 768 - 450 && mouseposy < 868)
                    if (Mouse::isButtonPressed(Mouse::Left))
                        MainMenu = false;



        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Q))
        {
            MainMenu == false;
            gameDisplay.close();

        }

        gameDisplay.draw(start);
        gameDisplay.draw(starttext);
        gameDisplay.display();
    }


   }
 };
```

things.h

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace sf;
using namespace std;
#pragma once
int RandomXpos = 0;

class Thing
{
public:
void thingspawn(RenderWindow &gameDisplay, int &enemystartx, int &enemystarty, int &enemywidth, int &enemyheight, RectangleShape &thing, int enemyspeed)
{
    thing.setFillColor(Color(255,255,255));
    if (thing.getPosition().y < 800)
        thing.move(0.0f, 0.4f);
    if (thing.getPosition().y >= 800)
    {
        RandomXpos = rand() % 1000;
        thing.setPosition(RandomXpos, -200);
    }

  }
 };
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "things.h"
#include "Main Menu.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace sf;




int main()
{
//FreeConsole();
RenderWindow gameDisplay(VideoMode(1366, 768), "Game");
gameDisplay.clear();
int enemystarty = -200;
int enemystartx = 300;
int enemyheight = 30;
int enemywidth = 300;
int enemyspeed = 0.3;
int enemycount = 1;
int dodged = 0;
int blockcolor = 0;
bool MainMenu = true;

int mouseposx = 0;
int mouseposy = 0;

Font font1;
if (!font1.loadFromFile("OCRAEXT.ttf"))
{
    //error...
}

/*
RectangleShape player(Vector2f(200, 50));
player.setFillColor(Color(0, 0, 255));
player.setPosition(400, 700);
*/

Texture playertexture;
if (!playertexture.loadFromFile("whiter_arrow.jpg"))
{
    //error...
}

Sprite player;
player.setTexture(playertexture);
player.setPosition(300, 600);

RectangleShape thing(Vector2f(enemywidth, enemyheight));
thing.setPosition(300, -200);

main_menu object;
object.startmenu(gameDisplay, font1, MainMenu, mouseposx, mouseposy);


while (gameDisplay.isOpen())
{
    Event evnt;
    while (gameDisplay.pollEvent(evnt))
    {
        switch (evnt.type)
        {
        case Event::Closed:
            gameDisplay.close();
        case Event::KeyPressed:
            if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Q))
                gameDisplay.close();

        }

    }


    while (MainMenu == false)
    {
        //gameDisplay.setMouseCursorVisible(false);

        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Right))
            if (player.getPosition().x < 1000)
            {
                player.move(0.3f, 0.0f);
            }

        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Left))
            if (player.getPosition().x > 50)
            {
                player.move(-0.3f, 0.0f);
            }
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Q))
            gameDisplay.close();


        Thing thingobject;
        thingobject.thingspawn(gameDisplay, enemystartx, enemystarty, enemywidth, enemyheight, thing, enemyspeed);


        gameDisplay.clear();
        gameDisplay.draw(player);
        gameDisplay.draw(thing);
        gameDisplay.display();
    }



   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put checking if button is clicked into event loop